# Getting "non-static method cannor be referenced from a static context here

Tags: static, non-static

So I know why this error appears in general, but I can't figure out why it appears here.
This is my code:

```
private void ausfuehrenFunktion(int funktion) {
artikel = new Artikel(einlesenArtikelnummer(), einlesenBezeichnung(), einlesenBestand(), einlesenPreis());
                Lager.legeAnArtikel(artikel);
}


public void legeAnArtikel(Artikel artikel){
        lager[stelle] = artikel;
        stelle++;          
    }
```

Comment: `legeAnArtikel` isn't static.

Comment: But it isn't supposed to, as I'm working with an object there?

Comment: Is `Lager` an object? I'd assume its a class.

Comment: It's both. It's a class and inside that class I create an array called Lager. The two methods are from different classes though.

Comment: An array has no method `legeAnArtikel` either. So you should replace `Lager` by an actual object name.

Comment: So I replaced "L" with "l" and it works now. Thanks a lot!